# Expression for $sin(x) + 2sin(2x) +...+nsin(nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm struggling with this problem,

Find an expression for $sin(x) + 2sin(2x)  +3sin(3x) + ... +nsin(nx)$

**Edit**

The problem states that I have to explicitly show that this series can be expressed as $\frac{((n+1)sin(nx) - nsin((n+1)x))}{sin^2(x/2)}$, where n can be any natural number and x can be any real.

Comment: Why not just let $x=\sin\theta$ in the expression you obtained? BTW, the expression is incorrect. You need to argue differently for $|x|<1$ and $|x|\ge 1$, and there shouldn't be some $n$ in RHS.

Comment: Your expression for $\sum nx^n$ doesn't make sense.  The left hand is not a function of $n$...the $n$ is just an index variable.  However your right hand is a function of $n$.

Comment: Similarly, the formula in your edit does not make any sense.  The starting expression, $\sum n\sin^n x$ is simply not a function of $n$.

Comment: How does it not make sense? If you let x be some complex number then you can apply de Moivre's formula to obtain part of the formula stated in the solution

Comment: Once again, $n$ is not a variable.  It is just a place holder for the index.  The final expression can not depend on $n$.

Comment: @lulu You're definitely correct, I've made an awful mistake; it's not an infinite series!

Answer (score 1):

No. We have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$

If $x $ is so that $|\sin(x)|=1$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\sin^nx$ is divergent.

If $x $ is so that $|\sin(x)|<1$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\sin^nx=\frac{1}{(1-\sin(x))^2}-\frac{1}{1-\sin(x)}$

Comment: You can simplify $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$.

Comment: Wow ! Yes, I know

Answer (score 1):

Use, when $\left|\text{f}\left(x\right)\right|<1$:

$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\text{n}\text{f}\left(x\right)^\text{n}=\frac{\text{f}\left(x\right)}{\left(\text{f}\left(x\right)-1\right)^2}$$

Now, when:

$$\text{f}\left(x\right)=\sin\left(x\right)$$

We get:

$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\text{n}\sin^\text{n}\left(x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\left(\sin\left(x\right)-1\right)^2}$$

We get, for the condition:

$$\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|<1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\left|e^{-xi}-e^{xi}\right|}{2}<1$$

For $x\in\mathbb{C}$:

1. $$e^{-xi}=\exp\left(-\left(\Re\left[x\right]+\Im\left[x\right]i\right)i\right)=\exp\left(\Im\left[x\right]\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\Re\left[x\right]i\right)$$
2. $$e^{xi}=\exp\left(\left(\Re\left[x\right]+\Im\left[x\right]i\right)i\right)=\exp\left(-\Im\left[x\right]\right)\cdot\exp\left(\Re\left[x\right]i\right)$$
3. $$\exp\left(-\Re\left[x\right]i\right)=\cos\left(\Re\left[x\right]\right)-\sin\left(\Re\left[x\right]\right)i$$
4. $$\exp\left(\Re\left[x\right]i\right)=\cos\left(\Re\left[x\right]\right)+\sin\left(\Re\left[x\right]\right)i$$

So:

$$e^{-xi}-e^{xi}=\left(\exp\left(\Im\left[x\right]\right)-\exp\left(-\Im\left[x\right]\right)\right)\cos\left(\Re\left[x\right]\right)-\left(\exp\left(\Im\left[x\right]\right)+\exp\left(-\Im\left[x\right]\right)\right)\sin\left(\Re\left[x\right]\right)i$$

So, for the absolute value:

$$\left|e^{-xi}-e^{xi}\right|=\sqrt{2\left(\cosh\left(2\Im\left[x\right]\right)-\cos\left(2\Re\left[x\right]\right)\right)}$$